# // answered thank u // Java reads certain amount of numbers outputs the product

Tags: java

Been able to write the code to read 4 numbers in the array and output the product of all numbers greater than / equal to zero. BUT, with the product of numbers less than zero, is different story.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int product = 1;
int negProduct = 1;

int[] array = new int[4];
System.out.println("Enter 4 integers");
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = scan.nextInt();

   if (array[i] >= 0) {
       product = product * array[i];
    }

    else {
        negProduct = negProduct * array[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Product of non-negatives = " + product);
    System.out.println("Product of negatives = " + negProduct);
}
```

This is the test code and how it runs

```
Enter 4 integers
2 6 -4 7

Product of non-negatives = 84
Product of negatives = -4
```

I've tried to have an if & else statement to make it run 0 instead of 1 for both negative and positives when there is none but haven't got it to work

Similarly to the 'else' statement but when I have it uncommented all answers are 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't that code to be in the loop, put it out of it

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = scan.nextInt();

    if (array[i] >= 0) {
       product *= array[i];
    } else {
        negProduct *= array[i];
    }
}

System.out.println("Product of non-negatives = " + product);
System.out.println("Product of negatives = " + negProduct);
```